# Rails 5 Production asset pipeline CSS not rendering

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails 5 webapp running on an ec2 instance. I have nginx successfully proxying to it. Nginx is serving up my stylesheets, but they just refuse to render on the page.

I'm using three gems that should have helped me out (They work perfectly in development mode):

```
// app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

@import "jquery-ui";
@import "dataTables/jquery.dataTables";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Rails asset pipeline compiles my CSS, capistrano deploys it to the public/assets/css folder, and I can see that nginx is serving it from the log file:

```
173.0.0.0 - - [24/Jan/2017:04:46:02 +0000] "GET /assets/application-4b2406f6ce6b47c29d7764376731b4a5862e841c272f0f6407f9e03fc6840986.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://54.0.0.0/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
```

Here's a snippet of my config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.quiet = false
config.cache_classes = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.public_file_server.enabled = false
```

But the page renders with *NO* css and looks totally plain in Chrome. So Frustrating!

Here is the kicker: It looks fine in Firefox.

QUESTION:
How to debug this? What tools to use?

Comment: Could it be cache related? You can disable the cache in Chrome by using developer tools or a extension.

Answer (score 0):

Derp. Max is totally right. Chrome from another computer works as well. I'll clear the cache on the computer I used last night and I'm pretty sure it will work.

Thanks Max! Gave an upvote.